# how can we have same post name for attachment and custom post type in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, attachment

In wordpress as far as I understand attachment(i.e.image) is also treated as a custom post type like other custom post type. So when I have 'staff' name as abc I can't have 'attachment' name as abc also( or else custom post type detail wont't work in front). This is the default feature of wordpress generated by get_page_by_path(). It generates the following query in wordpress

```
SELECT ID, post_name, post_parent, post_type
FROM wp_posts
WHERE post_name IN ('someslug')
AND post_type IN ('page','attachment')
```

Are there any alternative to make this work for both attachment and custom post type ?

Any help/suggestions are welcome.